# Find an ordered basis $B$ for $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $[T]B$ is a diagonal matrix for $n > 2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a homework problem that I'm stuck on. It is problem 5.1.17 in the Friedberg, Insel, and Spence Linear Algebra book for reference.

"Let T be the linear operator on $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $T(A) = A^t$" is the beginning of the problem.

The part I'm concerned with is part d, "Find an ordered basis $B$ for $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $[T]B$ is a diagonal matrix for $n > 2$?"

I completed part c), which is the same part but for $2\times2$ matrices instead.

I'm stuck on figuring this part out.

Comment: see https://math.solverer.com/library/stephen_friedberg/linear_algebra/exercise_5-1-17?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What matrices satisfy $A^\top =\lambda A$ for some $\lambda$?

Comment: Thanks! This was actually an earlier part (b), that found the eigenvalues to be +1 and -1. For +1, the corresponding matrices are nonzero symmetric matrices. For -1, the corresponding matrices are nonzero skew-symmetric matrices. So I know what matrices satisfy that equation. However, I'm not sure how to relate this to forming a basis that if a linear operator is written in that basis, it is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Well, you're almost there. If you show that every matrix can be written as a sum of a symmetric matrix and a skew-symmetric matrix, then you should be able to argue that you have a basis consisting of eigenvectors.

Comment: That sounds very reasonable. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry for asking so many questions, but I did a proof for showing that every square matrix can be written as a sum of a symmetric and skew-symmetric matrix. I'm having trouble connecting this to eigenvalues and how writing [T]B with respect to the basis makes a diagonal matrix.

Comment: A diagonal matrix is equivalent to a basis of eigenvectors. Go back to the definition of $[T]_B$. You will ultimately need a basis for the subspace of symmetric (skew-symmetric) matrices.

Comment: Note that this works because $\tfrac{1}{2} \in \Bbb{R}$ and would work over any other field in which $2$ has a multiplicative inverse.